# Cannot use EventTriggerBehavior with ScrollViewer's ViewChanged event

Tags: mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml

I try to use EventTriggerBehavior with ScrollViewer's ViewChanged event:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ViewChanged">
             <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding AddNextCommand}"
                   CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer}"/>
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ScrollViewer>
```

But it get an exception:

**Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException:** 'The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Cannot add instance of type 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core.EventTriggerBehavior' to a collection of type 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.BehaviorCollection'.

How to fix it?

I want to automate add new elements to view when ScrollViewer scrolls to bottom, are there other ways to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot add instance of type 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core.EventTriggerBehavior' to a collection of type 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity.BehaviorCollection'.

Firstly, this error indicates that the element does not have an event called `ViewChanged`. This is caused by you didn't allocate `SourceObject` for [`EventTriggerBehavior`](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/EventTriggerBehavior) that the  behavior  is attached to the wrong element which is not `scrollViewer`. You should set `SourceObject` like follows:

```
<core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="PointerPressed" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=scrollViewer}">
```

But even with this, you may get another error since `ViewChanged` may not be supported with `WindowsRuntimeMarshal.AddEventHandler`. Please try to invoke the [`ScrollViewer.ViewChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.viewchanged) event directly.

> I want to automate add new elements to view when ScrollViewer scrolls to bottom, are there other ways to do it?

Looks like [`ISupportIncrementalLoading`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.isupportincrementalloading) could help. Please try it.

Comment: Thank you. I solved this problem by using the Loaded event for EventTriggerBehavior, then register a ViewChanged event for the ScrollViewer in ViewModel. I will try your solution later, thank you again!